# Xamarin Shell : Pass multiple arguments to another page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have two pages in my Xamarin Forms Shell app.
One list page and another is the details page.
when I select the item in list page, the detail page will be shown. I was able to pass one parameter to the second page. I know how to pass the second value. But how should I receive the second value in the first property itself.

**List Page:**

```
        async private void myLines_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = (Models.QLines)e.Item;
            int pno = line.PageNo;
            int lno = line.LineNo;
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//mainTabs/pages?pageno={pno}&lineno={lno}");
        }
```

**Detail Page:**

```
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentLine { get; set; }
        public bool IsFromSearchPage { get; set; }

        public string PageNo
        {
            set
            {
                CurrentPage = Convert.ToInt32(Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
                IsFromSearchPage = true;

                LoadPagesAsSingle();
            }
        }

        public string LineNo
        {
            set
            {
                CurrentLine = Convert.ToInt32(Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
            }
        }

        public MyPages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteMyConnection>().GetConnection();

            IsFromSearchPage = false;

            LoadPagesAsSingle();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data you can use `QueryProperty` attribute to map between `queryID` and the target property:

```
[QueryProperty("Pageno", "pageno")]
[QueryProperty("Lineno", "lineno")]

public partial class DetailPage: ContentPage
{

        private int _Pageno;
        public int Pageno
        {
            get { return _Pageno; }
            set { _Pageno = value; }
        }

        private int _Lineno;
        public int Lineno
        {
            get { return _Lineno; }
            set { _Lineno = value; }
        }
```

Comment: it is not clear what do you mean by "I receive the second value in the first property itself."

Comment: Also I don't understand why to use UnescapeDataString if you can use QueryProperty, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: As another solution you can pass parameters through static members of page. For example page may contain static ViewModel object, which will be initialized before page appears.

Comment: @Cfun I'm already using ```QueryProperty```.  And I don't know if it is a good idea to call function ```LoadPagesAsSingle()``` in ```Property```. I tried it in constructor, but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

As another solution you can pass parameters through static members of page. For example page may contain static ViewModel object, which will be initialized before page appears.

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase   
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyPage : Page
    {
        static ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public MyPage() 
        {
            BindingContext = _viewModel;
        }

        public static void InitPage(string text, int number)
        {
            _viewModel.Text = text;
            _viewModel.Number = number;
        }
    }
}
```

Code inside caller

```
static async Task GotoPage()
{
    MyPage.InitPage("Text", 123);
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//mainTabs/pages");
}
```

Comment: The ViewModel need to be common between the two pages right?

Comment: Not needed. It is static object and rely only to MyPage only. So from another page, e.g. Page2 you should call MyPage.GotoPage() and it will pass paramaeters and navigate to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parameters in the **detailPage**

```
public DetailPage(string val1,string val2)
{

}
```

then call it in **MyPage**

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage("parameter1","parameter2"));
```