# How to inject thread ( Action ) ​to string in route navigation xamarin site

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin.forms, navigation, action

I want to inject System.Action to the view model via shell navigation.
I have this methode

```
public void SendBook(){..}
Public void GoToBooking(){
                Action action = new Action(() => SendBook(true));
                Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Booking), typeof(Booking));

                string actionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(action);

                var uri = $"{nameof(Booking)}?ContentThread={actionJson}&IsBooking=true";
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(uri);
}
```

So far, so good here ,
but in Booking.xaml.cs the data dosent injected

```
   [QueryProperty(nameof(ContentThread), nameof(ContentThread))]
   [QueryProperty(nameof(IsBooking), nameof(IsBooking))]

    public partial class Booking: ContentPage
    {
        public string ContentThread{ get; set; }
        public Booking()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //var actions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(ContentThread);// ContentThread is null

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var isBooking=isBooking;//true
            var actions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(ContentThread);ContentThread is null
            BindingContext = new BookingViewModel(actions);

        }
```

any ideas why ContentThread is null.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe that you can serialize an `Action`.  What does `actionJson` contain?  If you deserialize it does it actually repopulate an `Action` object?

Comment: @Jason thanks for ur answer , 
i serialized the action ( Method and target )  .. but i tried deserializing after serializing , i get error ( : 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method'
) , there is any other way ..

Comment: One work-around is to store the action "somewhere" that the receiver knows to look. One approach is to store the action in a static variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66305276/199364). Where the answer shows `static ViewModel _viewModel`, you would have `public static Action TheAction;`, and set that with `Booking.TheAction = action;` before doing GoToAsync. NOTE: This is a hack, as globals often are. Maybe someone knows a better way.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve u solved my problem , but as u said if there is another way else ill keep it